# Symfony 2 security - not having secured area under a prefix

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

Using Symfony 2 it's possible to create secured areas under a specific URL prefix. For example you could have a members area located under a 'members' prefix like so:

```
www.site.co.uk/members
www.site.co.uk/members/edit
www.site.co.uk/members/settings
```

Instead of doing this is it possible to put the whole app behind a firewall using `/` as the prefix? So the only pages visible to the public are the login and registration pages.

Anyone visiting `www.site.co.uk` who isn't logged in would see the login page. Once logged in visiting `www.site.co.uk` would show the app's home page instead. Both pages would be under the same route (`/`), you would just see one or the other depending on if you are logged in or not.

At the moment setting my firewall's pattern to `/` results in a redirect loop because my login form (which is under the homepage route '/') is then behind the firewall.

How do I got about implementing a login process as described above? Is it possible out of the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why nobody reads the part about access control?

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            # other settings
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: You would probably need to set `^/css` and `^/js` (and other root folder that everyone needs to be able to access for your site to work properly) to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` too.